# Internet Explorer 10 does not apply flexbox on inline elements

Tags: css, internet-explorer, inline, html, flexbox

According to [flexbox specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/#flex-items) a span flex item (children of a flex container) should be converted into `display:block`.
Internet Explorer 10 does not apply this transformation an thus flexbox does not work on span (inline) elements.

Here a [codepen](http://cdpn.io/iJhyu) of what I mean

I can just use divs but I would like to know if this is an explorer bug and if there is a better fix than changing the html code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just because the (working draft) flexbox spec changed, after IE10 was released.

Here's the relevant chunk of spec text from the CSS Flexbox working draft, as it existed when IE10 was released towards the end of 2012:

> The flex layout algorithm operates on boxes generated by flex items. Each of the following becomes a flex item:
>
> ```
> [...]
> ```
>
> 4. An anonymous block wrapped around a contiguous run of non-replaced inline child elements.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-flexbox-20120612/#flex-items

A `span` is a "non-replaced inline child element". So IE10 wraps the `span` (and any adjacent inline content) in an anonymous block (matching the old spec) instead of converting it *to* a block (per the new spec).

I suspect Microsoft didn't want to change this functionality after release, to avoid breaking content that was already coded to expect a particular behavior in IE10.

So if you want to write flexbox content that works *both* in IE10 *and* more recent browser-versions, it's probably best not to depend on this particular behavior. (Be explicit; change these spans to divs, or give them `display:block`, since you know they're going to be converted to blocks in newer browsers anyway.)

Comment: To be clear, IE followed the draft spec and not the final version. The spec did not change out from under them. Other browsers update more frequently and were able to catch up while IE, as always, trails far behind.

Comment: I edited my post to mention "working draft" in the first sentence, and remove "out from under"; hopefully that makes that clearer & more neutral-sounding.  (Also, you mentioned "final version" -- there is no "final version" yet. There are still (minor) behavior changes being proposed/discussed at the CSSWG. http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/ has the latest editor's draft (last updated a few days ago), and I know of several proposed changes that are still coming that haven't made it into that yet.)

Answer (score -3):

did you try this property?

`display:-ms-inline-flexbox;` (for an inline flexbox container).

Comment: In my case the childrens are inline not the parent. This does not work.